# Comparing two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have for example in the dataframe daily "AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,AMZN" and in weekly list "OAG,EXCA,AAPL,HRT,TSLA"

How can i compare the two dataframes and print out when a ticker is found in both lists?

```
dailyList = []
weeklyList = []

for ticker in tickers:
 dailyList.append(ticker)
 weeklyList.append(ticker) # append with some data like "AAPL"

compare(dailyList,weeklyList)
print(matchingTickers)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare the two list of tickers, you can try something like this:

```
daily =  set("AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,AMZN".split(","))
weekly = set("OAG,EXCA,AAPL,HRT,TSLA".split(","))
common = daily.intersection(weekly)
```

Here, `common` would be: `{'TSLA', 'AAPL'}`.